# How do I check permissions of a directory and all of its recursive content?

Tags: shell, file-permissions

I created a simple bash script that checks if a directory has the given permissions, then executes its task.

```sh
if [ `stat -c "%a" my_directory` != 777 ]; then
    # script to be executed
fi
```

Now, this works well, but it only checks for permissions of the given directory. I also need to check recursively for all of the content of `my_directory` if the permissions are set to something different than `777`.

In other words, this script should run as long as even a single file or directory inside `my_directory` has its permissions not set as `777`. If everything inside this directory is completely accessible, the script should not run.

How can I modify my script to make it work this way?

Comment: `find my_directory ! -perm 777`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jordanm's suggestion, I modified my script like this

```sh
checkfiles=0
declare -i checkfiles

for file in `find my_directory ! -perm 777`

do

    checkfiles+=1

done

if [ $checkfiles != 0 ]; then

    # script to be executed
    
fi
```